# Touch users can't drag and drop in React app

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, touch, dnd-kit

I followed the [quick start](https://docs.dndkit.com/introduction/getting-started#assembling-all-the-pieces) for the dnd kit React library, and it lets me drag and drop just fine with a mouse. However, when I try to use the same page with Chrome on Android, I can't drag the item. It looks like it starts moving and then gets stuck as soon as my finger moves outside its original border.

I tried switching to the drag overlay, but that didn't seem to make any difference.

How can I support touch users with dnd kit?

Answer (score 5):

It wasn't covered in the quick start, but I found the answer in the Draggable section's [recommendations](https://docs.dndkit.com/api-documentation/draggable#recommendations):

> In general, we recommend you set the `touch-action` property to `none` for draggable elements in order to prevent scrolling on mobile devices.

I found that I could either set the CSS style on the draggable element itself, or on a parent element that contains several draggable elements.

However, when I started trying to drag items around within a list or grid of items, that stopped working. Eventually, I had to switch from using the pointer sensor to using the mouse and touch sensors, as described in the [sensors section](https://docs.dndkit.com/api-documentation/sensors).

Comment: Yes, it worked for me too, but when I drag the list a lot, move elements up and down, sometimes it bugs. The element gets isDragging mode, but I does not move and when I scroll the page the element starts to move too with the page. I was trying to detect why that happens. Have you experienced same problem?